# C - Trouble passing structure pointers to function

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

When I compile this I get lots of errors saying each part of my `struct` is invalid, along the lines of:

`sort.c:16: request for member 'last' in something not a structure or union`

And for the cases where I use strcpy, the errors read:

`sort.c:18: warning: passing arg 2 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer type`

So I must be misusing the pointers...but I'm not sure why.

I have the `struct` defined in `DBrecord.h`:

```
typedef struct{
    int DBrecordID;         //ID for each entry, range 0-319
    char *last;             //student last name
    char *first;            //student first name
    char studentID[8];      //student ID
    int age;                //student age
    class year;             //year in school
    float gpa;              //GPA
    int expGradYear;        //expected graduation year
}DBrecord;


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "DBrecord.h"

void bubbleSort(DBrecord **record, int numEntries, int sortChoice) {
int i, j;
char temp[100];

for(i=0; i<numEntries; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < numEntries-1; j++)
        switch(sortChoice){
            //sort by last name
            case  1 : if(strcmp(record->last[j], record->last[j+1]) > 0){
                    //swap the two elements
                    strcpy(temp, record[j]);
                    strcpy(record[j], record[j+1]);
                    strcpy(record[j+1], temp);
                  }
            //sort by first name
            case  2 : if(strcmp(record->first[j], record->first[j+1]) > 0){
                    //swap the two elements
                    strcpy(temp, record[j]);
                    strcpy(record[j], record[j+1]);
                    strcpy(record[j+1], temp);
                  }
            //sort by student ID
            case  3 : if(atoi(record->studentID[j]) > atoi(record->studentID[j+1])){
                    //swap the two elements
                    temp = record[j];
                    record[j] = record[j+1];
                    record[j+1] = temp;
                  }
            //sort by age
            case  4 : if(atoi(record->age[j]) > atoi(record->age[j+1])){
                    //swap the two elements
                    temp = record[j];
                    record[j] = record[j+1];
                    record[j+1] = temp;
                  }
            //sort by class
            case  5 : if(record->class[j] > record->class[j+1]){
                    //swap the two elements
                    temp = record[j];
                    record[j] = record[j+1];
                    record[j+1] = temp;
                  }
            //sort by gpa
            case  6 : if(atoi(record->gpa[j]) > atoi(record->gpa[j+1])){
                    //swap the two elements
                    temp = record[j];
                    record[j] = record[j+1];
                    record[j+1] = temp;
                  }
            //sort by expected graduation year
            case  7 : if(atoi(record->expGradYear[j]) > atoi(record->expGradYear[j+1])){
                    //swap the two elements
                    temp = record[j];
                    record[j] = record[j+1];
                    record[j+1] = temp;
                  }
            default : break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `record` is a pointer to a pointer to a `DBrecord`, `record->last[j]` doesn't make any 
sense. The object at `record` (a pointer to a pointer) doesn't have a field called `last`; it has no fields at all, it's just a pointer.

You probably mean `record[j]->last`, to get the `last` member of the j:th DBrecord. And so on.

Comment: I do believe that's exactly what I mean...thanks bunches, trying now.

Answer (score 2):

Take `record->last[j]`. This is equivalent to `(*record).last[j]`. But `*record` is not a `struct`. It is of type `DBrecord*`. In other words you need to de-reference your pointer twice, but you have only de-referenced it once.

Comment: is this another way to do what unwind posted above?  That seemed to work, and now i just have 2 different errors, either `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` or `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: Well I don't know what you mean by `DBrecord**`. Is it an array of pointers to `DBrecord`. `record[j]` de-references `record` once and then `->` does a second de-reference.

Comment: so would I need to put `DBrecord.record[j]->last`?

Comment: No, that doesn't compile. I don't know what `record` is. I know it's type, but I don't know what it is. Only you know that.